# Search results issue

Tags: 7, search

I am using the drupal's built in search module, for this I have copied the `search-results.tpl.php` in my theme folder. Now I have to add images for search results too and also want to custom theme the template file. For images I have used the following approach:
In my `template.php`:

```
function MyTheme_preprocess_search_result(&$variables)
{
if ($result['node']->type == "content_type") {
 $node = node_load($result['node']->nid);
 $prod_image = field_view_field('node', $node, 'machine_name_img', $display = array());
 $variables['image'] = $prod_image;
}
}
```

and then in `search-result.tpl.php`:

```
<?php if($prod_image):?>
    <?php print render($prod_image);?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but its not working, can anybody knows how do I get the images related to search results, and how can I theme search results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong var name. In your preprocess function you're using `$variables['image'] = $prod_image;` to set the var. Whatever element name you use in the the `$variables` array will be the name of the var in the template. So in your case it should be:

```
<?php if($image):?>
    <?php print render($image);?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanku @Shawn, but still not working

Comment: Yeah its working now, in ` hook_preprocess_search_result(&$variables)` I have used `field_get_items('node',$node, 'machine_name_img')` before `field_view_field('node', $node, 'machine_name_img', $display = array())`

Answer (score 0):

You used some vars that don't even exist in this place.
template.php:

```
function MyTheme_preprocess_search_result(&$variables){
  if ($variables['result']['type'] == "content_type") {
   $node = node_load($variables['result']['node']->entity_id);
   $prod_image = field_view_field('node', $node, 'machine_name_img', $display = array());
   $variables['image'] = $prod_image;
  }
}
```

and then in search-result.tpl.php(like in the answer of @Shawn Conn):

```
<?php if(image): ?>
  <?php print render(image); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you get the correct return out of this, dependes on what the line `$prod_image = field_view_field('node', $node, 'machine_name_img', $display = array());` will return